# jsperf: Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to [use jsperf to check](https://jsperf.com/updating-lists-with-and-without-detaching/1) whether temporal detaching a container from `document` may speed up changing its content (removing/appending multiple elements). But the code that works for me in console gives me an error in jsperf.

Preparation:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul></ul>
</div>

// fill the list
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var listElement = container.firstChild;
var initialContent = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    initialContent += `<li>${i+1}</li>`;
listElement.innerHTML = initialContent;
```

teardown (it's important not to use `listElement.innerHTML = ''`):

```
while(listElement.firstChild)
    listElement.removeChild(listElement.firstChild);
```

main code to profile:

```
listElement = container.removeChild(listElement);
while(listElement.firstChild)
    listElement.removeChild(listElement.firstChild);
var newListItem;
for(var j = 100; j < 200; j++) {
    newListItem = document.createElement('li');
    newListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j));
    listElement.appendChild(newListItem);
}
container.appendChild(listElement);
```

the code to compare:

```
while(listElement.firstChild)
    listElement.removeChild(listElement.firstChild);
var newListItem;
for(var j = 100; j < 200; j++) {
    newListItem = document.createElement('li');
    newListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j));
    listElement.appendChild(newListItem);
}
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': This node type does not support this method..
>
> - message: Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
> - fileName: https://jsperf.com/updating-lists-with-and-without-detaching/1
> - lineNumber: 12

It goes away if I comment out the line `listElement.appendChild(newListItem);`

Adding a breakpoint via `debugger;` line shows me that `listElement` is somehow a text node..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured this out while posting this: using

```
var listElement = container.firstElementChild;
```

instead of

```
var listElement = container.firstChild;
```

fixed the issue. The source of the issue is whitespace in html

```
<div id="container">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

which makes `container.firstChild` a text node with text `'\n    '`. Probably I omitted the whitespace when I tested this without jsperf.

Hope this may be helpful for others searching this error.